# How to input dynamic key to json_extract mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, json, mysql-8.0, json-extract

I have one table (call it `abc`) like below:
[image]

The column named 'likelihood'is a JSON Object (key-value).
I have another table (lets call it `xyz`) that contains **CustomerId** and **key**(an integer value) columns.
I am joining the two tables above based on **customerid** like:
`Select xyz.customerid, key, label from xyz join abc on xyz.customerid = abc.customerid`

**Question**:
I want to find `label` against the key provided in the `key` column of table `xyz`, from the JSON Object of the column `likelihood` in the table `abc`.
All the examples of function `JSON_EXTRACT` that I have found, are passing hard coded key instead of some dynamic value of key taken from the database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First problem was: my JSON Object contains **keys** which are **integer** values & not alphabets or words. So in order to reference value with an integer as key, we need to write it down like:
`JSON_EXTRACT(json_object, '$."int_key"')`

Here is my solution:
`Select xyz.customerid,key,JSON_EXTRACT(abc.likelihood,concat('$."',xyz.key,'"')) as label from xyz join abc on xyz.customerid = abc.customerid;`